# Remove registered on-premises instances from CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-code-deploy

As you can see in the next image, got atm three instances registered

[image: CodeDeploy Registered Instances]

and would like to have none. If I click in one of them, for instances, this is the only thing I get

[image: Single Registered On-premises instance]

so there's not anywhere a button to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right term to be applied here is **deregister**. So, one wants to [deregister the on-premises instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/on-premises-instances-operations-deregister-manually.html).

Using AWS-CLI you can check the current instances that are registered using the following command

```
aws deploy list-on-premises-instances --region eu-west-2
```

This gives something like this with the names of the current registered instances

```
{
    "instanceNames": [
        "Amazon_Linux_1",
        "Amazon_Linux_2",
        "codedeploy"
    ]
}
```

To do unregister the instance named Amazon_Linux_1 run

```
aws deploy deregister-on-premises-instance --instance-name Amazon_Linux_1 --region eu-west-2
```

[image: Instance was unregistered]

Note: if you try to run it without the region, you'll get

> You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by
> running "aws configure".